# How to call web service in phonegap in android app?

Tags: cordova

I am beginner in phonegap. I have developed native apps in phonegap android. now this apps is only static, I want creat update button on my apps when i will clicked on 
update button then my webservice will called and this data stored locally in apps means in the local database.

Thanking you

Answer (score 2):

A simple example that I personally like can be found here: http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/10/sample-application-with-jquery-mobile-and-phonegap/. It works with PHP / MySQL web server

Answer (score 2):

A quick-and easy way is to call the service using AJAX, and you can use [HTML5's localStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) to store the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following lines of code to call the Web Service in PhoneGap:-

```
  $.post( url, { user_id:userID,password:password} , function( data ) {
                                                            if(data.status==true){

                                                                /*Your Code*/     
                                                            }else{
                                                                /*Your Code*/  

                                                            }
                                                          },"json");
```